# Make WordPress.com more prominent OpenID option

Tags: feature-request

In interface for OpenID login into the site, WordPress.com login option is buried in second tier services.

It would make sense for our stack if it was displayed more prominently as first tier option.

[image: SE OpenID options]

Comment: Why? `wordpress.com` is not even on topic here. Admins and devs don’t use it. `</devilsadvocate>`

Comment: @toscho google, facebook and yahoo aren't on topic either :) wordpress.com is common account to have in WP community, even among developers for self-hosted - thanks to it being required for WordPress.com API key

Comment: Any dev who works with core uses WP.com somewhat heavily for the http://make.wordpress.com sites. I think making that integration more prominent makes far more sense than logging in with Yahoo ...

Comment: I just wanted to illustrate the lack of arguments in this request. :P

Answer (score 7):

As @EAMann noted in the OP comments, pretty much all WordPress developers and community contributors have and use wordpress.com accounts, which are linked to the make.wordpress.org contributor sites.

Thus, making the wordpress.com OpenID provider link more prominent might encourage more such members to register/participate here at WPSE - *and these are exactly the sort of users we **want** to encourage to participate*. Anything we can do to facilitate such users to participate can only benefit the site.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Chip Bennett's answer, many WordPress users (and Stack Exchange users) would have a Gravatar account. Gravatar and WordPress.com accounts are essentially [one and the same - you can't have one without the other](http://blog.gravatar.com/2013/04/03/gravatar-and-wordpress-com-together-forever/).

Comment: Huh? I don't know if signing up for wp.com gives you gravatar account, but I am pretty sure you can sign up for gravatar and not have wp.com account. They are different services.

Comment: @Rarst According to [this recent blog post](http://blog.gravatar.com/2013/04/03/gravatar-and-wordpress-com-together-forever/), Gravatar accounts have always been WordPress.com accounts. They've just made this more promanent lately with the WordPress.com Connect buttons

Comment: it wasn't Automattic service originally so "always" is a stretch. :) Anyway now they are clearly smashed together. Painfully so - I couldn't get to my gravatar at all for some time after announcement.

Comment: @Rarst True enough :) Anyway, that was the state of things when I wrote this post; it just applies even more now